# QSplashScreen close on click

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

Fist of all I'll describe my goal: I'd like to inform user in blocking mode that there's some work in progress.

I hope if I disable hiding on click in QSplashScreen, this will fit my needs.
In C++ it's handled in mousePressEvent method:

```
void QSplashScreen::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *)

{
    hide();
}
```

so I hoped that just overriding of this method will supress hiding, but my code doesn't work:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import time

class MySplash(QtGui.QSplashScreen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySplash, self).__init__()
        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("betting.gif"))

    def mousePressEvent(self, mouse_event):
        print('mousePressEvent', mouse_event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash = MySplash()
    splash.show()
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
    print('Here I am')
    splash.showMessage('Here I am')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Do some work')
    time.sleep(2)
    splash.close()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why overriding mousePressEvent method doesn't work (I'm still interested in) but I solved my problem in other way:

```
class BusyDialog(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(BusyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.show()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Click me', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        print('clicked')
        dialog = BusyDialog()
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Here I am')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Do some work')
        time.sleep(2)
        dialog.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my initial question is simple: `mousePressEvent` is declared as protected - that's why it's not possible to override it!

Comment: If you inherit `QSplashScreen` there is nothing that prevents you from overriding/re-implementing it in your subclass. The member function is declared as virtual protected in `QSplashScreen`, i.e., it's designed to be overridden by subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method I have found is to take advantage of pythons loose function pointers.

Here is how I do it (without having to overload).

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QPixmap, QSplashScreen
import sys


def MyMousePressEvent(event):
    print "I was clicked, and I have an event!"
    print "see its at", event



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    splash_image = QPixmap(":Images/MyImage.png")
    splash = QSplashScreen(splash_image)
    splash.mousePressEvent = MyMousePressEvent
    splash.show()
    ## need to check the for events on a regular interval!
    time.sleep(2)
    app.processEvents()
    print('Here I am')
    splash.showMessage('Here I am')
    time.sleep(2)
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
    print('Do some work')
    time.sleep(2)
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
    splash.close()
    return app.exec_()
```

if you would like to have the click communicate with another object then add the method to that object and set it to QSplashScreen.mousePressEvent

```
class MyCommClass(QMainWindow,splashscreen,parent): ## mainwindow used here but it could be whatever

    def __init__(self,splashscreen = None,parent = None):  ## Create Mainwindow Obj
        QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent) ## Call base class CTOR
        if(splashscreen is not None):
            splashscreen.mousePressEvent = self.SplashMousePressEvent
        ##instead of splash.mousePressEvent = MyMousePressEvent

    def SplashMousePressEvent(self,event):
        print "Splash screen was clicked!"
        ## self.DoWhatEverIWant()
```

Hope that helps you.